# Spring Data JPA @OneToOne annotation Infinite Recursion Error

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

**Husband.java**

```
package com.example.demo.com.example.domain;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.*;


//@Data
//@NoArgsConstructor
//@EqualsAndHashCode
//@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_husban")
public class Husband {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String job;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "wife_fk",referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Wife wife;

    //omitted getter/setter
}
```

**Wife.java**

```
package com.example.demo.com.example.domain;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.*;

//@Data
//@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "husband",callSuper = false)
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_wife")
public class Wife {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "wife",cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private Husband husband;

    //omitted getter/setter
}
```

**Service.java**

```
@Service

    public class TestOneToOneEitherSide {

        @Autowired
        private WifeRepository wifeDao;

        @Autowired
        private HusbandRepository husbandDao;
        public Husband testCreate() {

            Husband husband = husbandDao.findByName("Wang");
            return husband;
        }
    }
```

When I query husband from database using spring data jpa,it occurs nfinite recursion in the result,seeing the follow picture.What's something wrong while using @OneToOne annotation？Could anybody give me some advice? Or I use the annotation in wrong way.

[the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQumL.png)

Comment: you are returning it back in a controller right?

Comment: You mean an infinite recursion in **JSON**, and not in JPA? So the problem is in your JSON usage presumably. So step backwards and see what JPA generated, and then what you are passing across, so you can see the step that causes it ... aka debugging

Comment: It occurs **stackoverflowerror** when returning **husband** to Controller.So it may be something wrong in the huasband entity.There is  infinite recursion in the query result, husbandDao.findByName("Wang")

Comment: so show the stack trace if it is in Java code ...

Comment: `Husband["wife"]->com.example.demo.com.example.domain.Wife["husband"]->com.example.demo.com.example.domain.Wife["husband"]->com.example.demo.com.example.domain.Husband["wife"]->com.example.demo.com.example.domain.Husband["wife"]->com.example.demo.com.example.domain.Wife["husband"]->com.example.demo.com.example.domain.Wife["husband"])] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
 at java.io.IOException.<init>(IOException.java:58) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException.<init>(JsonProcessingException.java:25) ~[jackson-core-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known issue, when you have bidirectional relation jackson will try to serialize each reference of one side from the other side so its logical to have infinite recursion.

Solution: There are many solutions to that , you could use @JsonIgnore on one side to avoid serializing the annotated reference hence breaking the infinite recursion

```
 @EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "husband",callSuper = false)
 @Entity
@Table(name = "t_wife")
public class Wife {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String name;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "wife",cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JsonIgnore
private Husband husband;

//omitted getter/setter
}
```

you also could use @JsonManagedReference/@JsonBackReference, check this [link](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) for more info how to use them

This answer has one problem , if you try to serialize wife direction you will not have husband object since the solution was to avoid serializing it.

There is a nice solution to this, its mentioned in this [link](https://www.toptal.com/javascript/bidirectional-relationship-in-json) , the idea is to generate a reference to the parent entity, so if you are serializing husband, you will have husband->wife->[reference to husband instead of husband], all you need to do is to annotate your entities with @JsonIdentityInfo

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "husband",callSuper = false)
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_wife")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class Wife {

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class, property="@id")
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_husban")
public class Husband {
@Id
```

Comment: It works fine and it can be written out to HTML page.But when I debug in **IDEA**,I find there still is an infinite recursion,seeing the link.[pic link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQumL.png).Would it cause the stack overflow error?

Comment: @Holinc no it would not , this is not an infinite recursion, you see it like this on the debugger since every side of the relation is mapping to the other side, that is expected

Answer (score 3):

You Should use @JsonBackReference with owning entity and @JsonManagedReference with child containing entity classes.

```
@JsonManagedReference
@Onetoone
private Queue queues;



    @Onetoone
    @JoinColumn(name = "qid")
   // @JsonIgnore
    @JsonBackReference
    private Queue_group queue_group;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lombok's **@ToString.Exclude** on the husband field or wife field to break the cycle references, either jackson will try to serialize each reference back and forth infinitely.

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "wife",cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@ToString.Exclude
private Husband husband;
```

or

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "wife_fk",referencedColumnName = "id")
@ToString.Exclude
private Wife wife;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way to avoid this kind of problems is to create DTO(Data Transfer Object) or simple pojos to your Entity classes. And dont experiment with json serialization management or messing Entities with as @Transient options)

Use Entities only for data persistance as Jpa stands for. (Use Entity to hold and manage data) and use DTOs or POJOs to transfer and communicate over api, etc. Furthermore I use many kind of Dtos for one giant Entity to make things easier to fetch some specifical works.