# Hibernate Infinite recursion in One-To-One relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, recursion, one-to-one

I have a mid-size project that is using One-To-One and One-To-Many relationships. Days ago, I got an Infinite recursion in **One-To-Many** relationships, but I managed to fixed it with those two annotations: **@JsonManagedReference** and **@JsonBackReference**.

Now I am facing the same error, but in **One-To-One** relationship. And it is not in "couple of fields" but just at one. Let me post some code. I have an Employee and a Task classes. One Employee has one Task at the time. So:

**Employee.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {


int id;
@NotNull
String firstName;
private Task taskRefference;

public Employee() {
    }

public Employee(firstName) {
this.firstName = firstName;
    }

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "task_id")
    public Task getTaskRefference() {
        return taskRefference;
    }

public void setTaskRefference(Task taskRefference) {
        this.taskRefference = taskRefference;
    }
```

**Task.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "task")
public class Task {
int id;
    @NotNull
    String title;
    @NotNull
    String assignees;

private Employee employee;

public Task(String title, String assignees) {
        this.title = title;
        this.assignees = assignees;
    }

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "taskRefference")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }
```

**Repository**

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
    Employee findById(int id);
}
```

**The controller**

```
  @Autowired
        EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/listEmployees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public List<Employee> listAllEmployees() {
            return employeeRepository.findAll();
        }
```

**Exception**: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.models.dto.Task["employee"]->com.models.dto.Employee["taskRefference"]->com.models.dto.Task["employee"]->com.models.dto.Employee["taskRefference"] (and it continues 100 lines the same loop)

Comment: what action causes this exception?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski from what I'm understanding, serializing the object to Json

Comment: See if this answer using @JsonIdentityInfo works for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45783753/spring-data-jpa-onetoone-annotation-infinite-recursion-error

Comment: The problems is caused when I want to print all of the Employees or all of the Tasks. I am using JPA Repo. I will upload my answer, forgot to mention it.

Comment: @Berger thank you, that link helped me ! I put JsonIgnore at taskRefference in my Employee.java and it worked. But do you have any idea how it could work with JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference ? Is it "professional" to be with JsonIgnore ?