# Spring Data JPA infinite recursion

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, spring-data-jpa

I've seen this problem pop up everywhere, and while i followed their solutions and it fixed my problem, i don't really understand what is happening. My Entities:

```
@Entity
public class ItemInOrder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    Bill bill;

    String comment;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class, property="@id")
    public class Bill {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        int id;

        @OneToOne
        Table table;



        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bill")
        List<ItemInOrder> itemi_vo_naracka = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

---

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class Table {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;

    @OneToOne
    Bill order_na_ovaa_masa;
}
```

My error comes when i call a basic JPA repository method to find all the ItemsInOrder:

```
return itemInOrderService.getAllItemsInOrder();


The exception says that the infinite loop is happening between Table and Bill:
Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: bla.bla.domain.Bill["table"]->bla.bla.domain.Table["order_na_ovaa_masa"]-> and so and so on..
```

- So can someone explain to me what was happening before i added the
  @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class,
  property="@id") above my entites, and what is happening after that.

  I've read a few explanations but i don't really understand whats happening with all that serialization and deseralization. If the explanation is too long, a guide or link to a post where it is explained nicely would also do(for a complete beginner in all of this). Thanks!

Comment: Are you referring to this answer being confusing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45783753/spring-data-jpa-onetoone-annotation-infinite-recursion-error?rq=1

Comment: I am referring mostly to the basic concept of serialization and how, in my situation, from ItemsInOrder it went and got stuck in between Table and Bill.

Comment: This probably explains it better than I can in a comment. https://www.toptal.com/javascript/bidirectional-relationship-in-json

Comment: Basically, in Java, Bill has a reference to Table and vice versa.Two objects with references. When deserializing, Jackson sees a Bill with a Table, and creates a new Bill that's identical to the old Bill, and gives it to the Table, forever, because it's just following the logic of the JSON and doesn't see self-referencing by default. With the identity, Jackson can map it to that reference instead, so the Table in Bill is mapped back to the original Bill, rather than to a new Bill. Hopefully this one makes slightly more sense.

Comment: Also, from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302816/how-to-use-jsonidentityinfo-with-circular-references `@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")` this could also replace your current @id as your objects do already have (hopefully unique) ids attached.

Comment: Hey the second link you sent me has been great and helped me fully understand what was going on. If you wanna put it in answer i will gladly give you accepted answer :)

Comment: I will mark as a duplicate of the original question as the link came from in there, though it's hidden in the middle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Data JPA @OneToOne annotation Infinite Recursion Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45783753/spring-data-jpa-onetoone-annotation-infinite-recursion-error)

Answer (score 0):

Look here, you have to annotate your list with :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "bill")
@JsonIgore
List<ItemInOrder> itemi_vo_naracka = new ArrayList<>();
```