# Getting error when trying to fetch data from relational entity in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, relational-database

Only `createOwner()` method is working from controller, but when trying to fetch data using `findById()` or `findAll()` getting a big exception.. as a new in spring boot don't know where is my fault. please help me if you can.

Sending this value from postman to save data of an entity which is saved successfully:

```
{        "ownerName": "Harry",
        "car":{
            "car_id" : "2"
        }
}
```

Owner Entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Owner {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long owner_id;

    private String ownerName;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "c_id", referencedColumnName = "car_id" )
    private Car car;

}
```

Car Entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long car_id;
    private String car_name;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "car")
    private Owner owner;
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class OwnerController {

    @Autowired
    private OwnerRepository ownerRepo;


    @PostMapping("/createowner")
    public Owner createOwner(@RequestBody Owner owner){
        return ownerRepo.save(owner);
    }

    @GetMapping("/findownerbyid")
    public Owner getByID(){
        return ownerRepo.findById(2L).get();
    }


    @GetMapping("/carlist")
    public List<Owner> getOwnerList(){
        return ownerRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

Owner Repo:

```
@Repository
public interface OwnerRepository extends JpaRepository<Owner, Long> {
}
```

Car Repo:

```
@Repository
public interface CarRepo extends JpaRepository<Car , Long> {
}
```

Owner database:

```
+----------+------------+------+
| owner_id | owner_name | c_id |
+----------+------------+------+
|        1 | Tom        |    1 |
|        2 | Harry      |    2 |
+----------+------------+------+
```

Car db:

```
+--------+----------+
| car_id | car_name |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | Toyota   |
|      2 | Audi     |
+--------+----------+
```

The error I am getting when calling "getOwnerList()" from postman:
https://pastehub.net/91fa43fc3f8

The error I am getting when calling "getOwnerList()" from postman:
https://pastehub.net/8171b4065ec

Comment: Not sure if it will solve the problem, but I notice you are using underscores in your naming convention i.e. `car_id`. While this is the naming convention for sql, camel case is preferred in Java `carId`. Using this naming convention, it should infer that the db column is `car_id`. To make sure all names are corresponding correctly, you can use the column annotation on each field such as `@Column(name=“car_id”)`

Comment: It would also allow us to assist you further if you could include the stack trace for the exceptions you’re getting.

Comment: @calvin-p change is column name but not solved. added both exceptions in the question check that out please

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after reviewing the stack trace, this is an issue with infinite recursion while serializing the object. As stated in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45783753/spring-data-jpa-onetoone-annotation-infinite-recursion-error), you can resolve this by adding the `@JsonIgnore` annotation in your Car entity.

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "car")
@JsonIgnore
private Owner owner;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you just saved me! i am struggling for two days with this problem